# Python ternary operator failure on dictionary

Tags: python

Original code: for dictionary `d1`, if `d1[w]` does not exist, initialize it to 1. Increment it otherwise.

```
if d1.get(w) == None:
    d1[w] = 1
else:
    d1[w] += 1
```

However, using ternary operator fails on this.

```
d1[w] = 1 if d1.get(w) == None else d1[w] += 1
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Typo there, remove the `=`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
d1[w] = 1 if d1.get(w) == None else d1[w] += 1
```

to

```
d1[w] = 1 if d1.get(w) == None else d1[w] + 1 # '+' instead of '+='
```

or, as [@vaultah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/vaultah) suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136005/python-ternary-operator-failure-on-dictionary/35136032#comment57992022_35136032) :

```
d1[w] = d1.get(w, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Or `d1[w] = d1.get(w, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG I see, the "1 if d1.get(w) == None else d1[w] + 1" is one expression. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SamShen you're welcome

Comment: @vaultah This is using dict.get(key, default=None). Thanks!